# Bug with the python list, it changes two thing of differents elements even I had commanded to change only one

Tags: python

I had had a problem with python, this only line change 2 elements of my list even I had commanded to change only one:

```
        print(Jogadores[i])
        print(Jogadores[i + 1])
      ->Jogadores[i][1][0][3] = novo_val
        print(Jogadores[i])
```

The prints around assure that this thing is happen in that exact line and I  don't know because it doesn't make the minimum sense.  What did this happen?

Following  the output bellow:

['cuca', [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, [0, 0, 0], 0]]]

['luca', [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, [0, 0, 0], 0]]]

['cuca', [[0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, [0, 0, 0], 0]]]

['luca', [[0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, [0, 0, 0], 0]]]

Following the code bellow:

`````
Jogadores =[]
dados = [0]*5
tabela = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,[0,0,0],0]]


num_jogadores=0
partidas = 0

def Inst_jogo():
    global num_jogadores
    global partidas
    global tabela
    global Jogadores
    nome = ""
    aux_jogadores= []
    aux_tabela = {}
    num_jogadores = int(input("Qual o número  de jogadores ?\n"))
    i = 0
    while(i < num_jogadores):
        nome = input("Qual o nome do jogador" + str(i+1) + " ?\n")
        aux_tabela = tabela
        Jogadores.append([nome, aux_tabela])
        i+=1
    partidas = input("Quantas terá o jogo ?\n")

def manipula_tabela(nome_jogador,secao_tab,componente_tab, novo_val):
    global Jogadores
    global num_jogadores
    if(novo_val < 0):
        print("Erro: novo valor inválido\n")
        return
    i = 0

    while Jogadores[i][0] != nome_jogador:
        i+=1
        if(i > num_jogadores - 1):
            print("Erro: Jogador não encontrado!\n")
            return


    if secao_tab == "sc_superior":
        print("entrou sc sup\n")
        if componente_tab == "um":
            if Jogadores[i][1][0][0]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'um'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
                return
            Jogadores[i][1][0][0] = novo_val
        elif componente_tab == "dois":
            if Jogadores[i][1][0][1]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'dois'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
                return
            Jogadores[i][1][0][1] = novo_val
        elif componente_tab == "tres":
            if Jogadores[i][1][0][2]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'tres'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
            Jogadores[i][1][0][2] = novo_val
        elif componente_tab == "quatro":

            if Jogadores[i][1][0][3]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'quatro'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
                print(Jogadores[i])
            print(Jogadores[i])
            print(Jogadores[i + 1])
            Jogadores[i][1][0][3] = novo_val
            print(Jogadores[i])
            print(Jogadores[i + 1])
        elif componente_tab == "cinco":
            if Jogadores[i][1][0][4]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'cinco'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
            Jogadores[i][1][0][4] = novo_val
        elif componente_tab == "seis":
            if Jogadores[i][1][0][5]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'seis'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
            Jogadores[i][1][0][5] = novo_val
        elif componente_tab == "pts_total":
            if Jogadores[i][1][0][6]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'pt_total'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
            Jogadores[i][1][0][6] = novo_val
        else:
            print("Compenente inexistente na seção superior!\n")
    elif secao_tab == "sc_inferior":
        if componente_tab == "trinca":
            if Jogadores[i][1][1][0]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'trinca'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
                return
            Jogadores[i][1][1][0] = novo_val
        elif componente_tab == "quadra":

            if Jogadores[i][1][1][1]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'quadra'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
                return
            Jogadores[i][1][1][1] = novo_val
        elif componente_tab == "full_house":
            if Jogadores[i][1][1][2]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'full_house'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
                return
            Jogadores[i][1][1][2] = novo_val
        elif componente_tab == "seq_max":
            if Jogadores[i][1][1][3]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'seq_max'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
                return
            Jogadores[i][1][1][3] = novo_val
        elif componente_tab == "seq_min":
            if Jogadores[i][1][1][4]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'seq_min'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
                return
            Jogadores[i][1][1][4] = novo_val
        elif componente_tab == "yathezz":
            if(Jogadores[i][1][1][5][0] == 0):
                Jogadores[i][1][1][5][0] = novo_val
            elif(Jogadores[i][1][1][5][1] == 0):
                Jogadores[i][1][1][5][1] = novo_val
            elif (Jogadores[i][1][1][5][2] == 0):
                Jogadores[i][1][1][5][2] = novo_val
            else:
                print("Atenção: número de yathezz excedido, não foi possível realizar alteração\n")
        elif componente_tab == "chance":
            if Jogadores[i][1][1][6]!= 0:
                print("Erro, não foi possível atualizar 'dois'. Número de atualizações exedida\n")
                return
            Jogadores[i][1][1][6] = novo_val
        else:
            print("Erro:Compenente inexistente na seção inferior!\n")
    else:
        print("Erro: Seção inexistente na tabela.\n")
    print("loop!\n")


#test: Essa parte é descartável.
Inst_jogo()
print("Partidas: " + str(partidas) +"\n" + "num_jogadores: " + str(num_jogadores) + "\n" )
manipula_tabela("cuca","sc_superior","quatro", 35)
#manipula_tabela("cuca","sc_inferior","quadra", 35)

i = 0
while(i < num_jogadores):
    print(Jogadores[i])
    i+=1````


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CarYv.png
`````

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is exactly here:

`while(i < num_jogadores):
        nome = input("Qual o nome do jogador" + str(i+1) + " ?\n")
        aux_tabela = tabela
        Jogadores.append([nome, aux_tabela]) ##aux_tabela(Portuguese) = aux_table(English)
        i+=1`

> When I give this order:  "aux_tabela = tabela", the program did a shallow copy. It means that for each player, all sub-list aux-table for each player is pointed for the same place. So when you ask to the program to change some of these sublist you are asking to it change all sublist,because even though the tables of each player are in different elements of the list(players), they are pointed for the same place and then any change in any table sublist will change all sub-list. To copy your list, but to have different address for each one, in other other, all pointed for different address, you need use the library "copy" and use "aux_tabela = copy.deepcopy(tabela)" instead "aux_tabela = tabela", do that you are doing a deep copy and then a small change in one element doesn't affect others.

To more details, you can read the link below:

[Deep Copy vs Shallow copy](https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/)